# Tracking when an entity or its relations have been updated

Tags: symfony, doctrine, timestamp

I am using Symfony 2.4 and doctrine ORM. I have a parent entity, Property, which has many child relations including:

- propertyVideos (OneToMany)
- propertyPhotos (OneToMany)
- propertyLocation (OneToOne)

In the lastUpdated field of the Property entity, I need to store the date and time of the last update of the Property entity **or any of its related entities**.

Is there an easy way to do this in Symfony/Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest bet would be to use the `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` or (for Symfony) `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` which you can then use the do the following...

```
Entity\Article:
    type: entity
    table: articles
    fields:
        created:
            type: date
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: create // $this create
        updated:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: update // $this update
        published:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestmpable:
                    on: change
                    field: type.title
                    value: Published
                              // $this->type->title changed to "Published"
        blah:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: change
                    field: type.somethingelse
                              // $this->type.somethingelse is changed
    manyToOne:
        type:
            targetEntity: Entity\Type
            inversedBy: articles
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what about tracking the changes of oneToMany relationships? How would that be handled?

Comment: @user3009816 I was looking for the same thing, but we have to handle it manually using a doctrine listener or the lifecycle event, as said [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1435) by bundle's author